# MSBuild task configuration property

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have three Visual Studio solutions. The first is configured to build as *Release*, and the other two are set to build as *Debug*.

When running a simple [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) script explicitly stating the configuration to build (Debug), the first project is still built as Release.

Sample script:

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(SolutionsPath)\Solution1.sln"/>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(SolutionsPath)\Core\Solution2.sln"/>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(SolutionsPath)\UI\Solution3.sln"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)"
             Targets="Rebuild"
             Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=Any CPU"/>
</Target>
```

I have tried variations of the above such as the following, but I always end up with the same result.

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(SolutionsPath)\Solution1.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Debug</Properties>
        </ProjectToBuild>

        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(SolutionsPath)\Core\Solution2.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Debug</Properties>
        </ProjectToBuild>

        <ProjectToBuild Include="$(SolutionsPath)\UI\Solution3.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Debug</Properties>
        </ProjectToBuild>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)"
             Targets="Rebuild"
             Properties="Platform=Any CPU"/>
</Target>
```

I note there is a similar question, *[MSBuild task - Build fails because one solution being built in release instead of debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474403)*, but that is specific to TFS and Teambuild. I am talking pure MSBuild with a simple project file created from scratch.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I have found the issue. Nothing related to MSBuild, but instead the solution being built. Posting to save someone else the heartache.

For whatever reason the Debug configuration was configured within the solution like so:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cad0bdf1c0.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cad0bdf1c0.jpg)

So MSBuild was only doing what it was told too...

Comment: I think it was all of those tiny little ants.

Comment: Image link broken, consider posting actual source code.

Answer (score 27):

Regarding the question of spelling of platform any cpu, it turns out there is an issue, already reported elsewhere here on StackOverflow and Microsoft. It affects MSBuild in general and the entire issue of `Platform` documentation is omitted in my dotnet v3.5 MSBuild /help. So perhaps this will help someone!

### Links

["AnyCPU" vs "Any CPU" in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957672/anycpu-vs-any-cpu-in-tfs-2010)
[MSBuild inconsistent platform for "Any CPU" between solution and project](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503935/msbuild-inconsistent-platform-for-any-cpu-between-solution-and-project)

```
Closed as Won't Fix   
Type:  Bug
ID:  503935  
Opened:  10/26/2009 1:29:12 PM
Access Restriction:  Public  
0 Workaround(s)
5 User(s) can reproduce this bug
```

The MSBuild `Platform` property has a **different value** for `Any CPU` depending upon whether you are **building a solution or building a project**.
- for **Solution** - use `Platform="Any CPU"` - **with space**
- for **Project** - use `Platform="AnyCPU"` - **without space**

Comment: This has got to be one of the worst decisions I've ever seen by a Microsoft team.

Comment: New bug for VS2013 posted here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/932918/solution-and-project-have-different-values-for-any-cpu#

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this same error. The solution was to explicitly specify the target platform with:

```
msbuild.exe /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

This only started happening since I upgraded to windows 7, so I guess it is something to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running with /v:diag?

Also, aside: I think you want "AnyCPU" (no space).

Comment: FYI Any CPU is correct...

: error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|AnyCPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU")

Comment: Had the same thing...looking into the .csproj file the platforms there were named AnyCpu (no whitespace) so changing this in the buildscript solved the problem.