# Building both solutions and projects using the same TFS Build definition

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm attempting to have a TFS 2012 build definition that contains both solution files and project files.

When the build runs, the solutions don't get build. Instead, I get warnings like:

> F:\Source\1\MyCode\src\MySolution.sln.metaproj: The specified solution configuration
>   "Release|AnyCPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution
>   configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g.
>   MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU")
>   or leave those properties blank to use the default solution
>   configuration.

This is caused by a bug that results in Visual Studio using "Any CPU" for the platform for solution files, while it uses "AnyCPU" for project files. See: 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/503935/msbuild-inconsistent-platform-for-any-cpu-between-solution-and-project

Is there a way to configure my build to make this work despite the issue? I.e., a way to pass a particular platform value to a specific sln build command while passing a different value to other commands?

Comment: Have you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957672/anycpu-vs-any-cpu-in-tfs-2010

Comment: New bug for VS2013 posted here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/932918/solution-and-project-have-different-values-for-any-cpu#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your solution.

From the **Build** menu click **Configuration Manager**.

From the **active solution platform** drop down, select **New**.  Create a **New Platform** called "Any CPU" and **Copy Settings From** the AnyCPU configuration.

Click **OK**

From the **active solution platform** drop down, select **Edit**.

Select "AnyCPU" and click **Remove**.

OK to close all all dialogs, then CTRL+SHIFT+S to save your solution file.

Now when you build the solution the platform should be identical.

Answer (score 5):

How about editing your `.csproj` you build individually and adding the `Or '$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU'` to `Platform` property's default condition to override/trim the space?

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' Or '$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```