# Why does C#/MSBuild spontaneously use a different output path for different projects?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

When I have a C# console application `foo`, and I compile it with

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Sometimes the resulting executable is

```
bin\Any CPU\Debug\net7.0\foo.exe"
```

and sometimes

```
bin\Debug\net7.0\foo.exe
```

Why?

Note:

- There is no `OutputPath` element in any of the project files.
- I am not asking how to change the behavior, but why it is currently as it is.

Comment: Did you have a look @ [dotnet/sdk Issue: Inconsistent target path between solution build and project build when platform specified #10188](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10188)?

Comment: According to [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022#use-msbuild-at-a-command-prompt): _For .NET Core and .NET 5 or later, you typically use [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) to invoke MSBuild_.

Comment: According to [.NET project SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview): _.NET Core and .NET 5 and later projects are associated with a software development kit (SDK). Each project SDK is a set of MSBuild targets and associated tasks that are responsible for compiling, packing, and publishing code...On a Windows machine, the Sdk.props and Sdk.targets files can be found in the %ProgramFiles%\dotnet\sdk\[version]\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk folder_

Comment: If one looks at _%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\sdk\7.0.404\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.DefaultOutputPaths.targets_ one sees **AnyCPU** in the code - notice that there isn't a space. However, it appears the documentation for [Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022) seems to list **Any CPU** instead of **AnyCPU**. Have you tried **AnyCPU** (without the space)?

Comment: One observes the same in _Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957672/anycpu-vs-any-cpu-in-tfs-2010 and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7310

Comment: @SirRufo That's the answer, thanks!

Comment: @rwallace If possible, could you please summarize and post an answer, others who meet the similar issue may need this. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sir Rufo for https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10188 which turned out to be the clue to the answer: it depends on whether MSBuild is working from a `.sln` or `.csproj` file. It defaults to the former if present, which means it produces different results for a single-project solution with both files in the same directory, versus a multi-project solution.