# MSBuild builds defaults to debug configuration

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I am trying to use MSBuild release mode, but it always defaults to debug. Any idea why?

```
msbuild LP.sln /p:buildmode=release
```

I checked through the following posts;

[MSBuild task - Build fails because one solution being built in release instead of debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474403/msbuild-task-build-fails-because-one-solution-being-built-in-release-instead-of)

[MSBuild task configuration property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721173/msbuild-task-configuration-property/729557#729557)

Comment: How did you verify that your build was a debug build ?

Comment: What do you mean i checked what directory was created

Answer (score 81, accepted):

That depends on the contents of that buildscript. Visual Studio C# uses the parameter *Configuration* to switch between *Release* and *Debug*. Not buildmode. You might want to try the following:

```
msbuild LP.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```