# How to specify "Release" instead of debug in MSBuild task?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have a CI Pipeline that builds .NET using MSBuild.

Is the MSBuild by default set to deploy in Release mode? If not, how do we specify it to build in release mode?

Do we specify that in the MSBuild task `configuration` field? simply type `release`?

[image: configuration]

what i mean by debug vs release, this is how we deploy as release manually today, which we'd like to be done by the pipeline instead to completely automate the build process.

[image: release]

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070146/8397835) but its more relevant to tfsbuild, not Azure Devops

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629779/msbuild-builds-defaults-to-debug-configuration Clearly the "Configuration" field is there.

Comment: @LexLi well i suppose that answers my question haha. I know it was there but I wasnt sure if it was set to build in release mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default it's set to build in debug mode:

[image: debug]

After specifying in "configuration" field "Release", the pipeline successfully built in Release mode.

[image: release mode]

[image: release]